# What's the best way to debug a nuget package with its souce code?

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I'm using a NuGet package in my project and sometimes I need to debug into the source code.

The NuGet package itself is open sourced on github.com so its source code can be downloaded as well. I can build and generate .dlls on my local computer.

But during my debugging, I can see the function names of the package, and even the file path of the source code (or course it's from someone else's computer), but it's grayed out and I can not double click to go into the source code. I checked the right-click menu, there's no way to load symbols there.

In this case, how can I let visual studio load the debug symbols so I can debug into the package's source code?

Comment: Is my answer helpful for you? Could you debug the Package now? If you get any latest information, please feel free to let me know:)

Comment: The best way is to [add SourceLink to debug the lib](https://blog.nuget.org/20180827/Introducing-Source-Code-Link-for-NuGet-packages.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you install the specific package in your project, if you want to debug the package in your project, you could add the source file to the solutions Common Properties -> Debug Source Files list.

If you download the source code of the package and open/compile it in your VS, I think you could refer them manually to your previous project, and then debug it directly like add breakpoint or others as general class library project.

Reference:

[How to debug using Nuget source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972844/how-to-debug-using-nuget-source-code)

[How to debug into my nuget package deployed from TeamCity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857780/how-to-debug-into-my-nuget-package-deployed-from-teamcity)

Comment: Yes, the source code can be debugged once it's added __manually__, but it's very tedious when there are several projects in a solution.